# SharePoint 2013 Token not refreshing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, smtp, token

What does it mean from the below uls log entry 
"Skip refresh token, because the token in memory is not fresh" 
Here what token is it referring too? SharePoint Token for service account or anything else? 
[image]

Comment: all alerts stopped or some works and some not?  I am thinking it more connection with SMTP server....could you please try to connect SMTP server from the sharepoint server, send email using command line

Comment: it was only for that particular time frame, and it happened thrice in past 4 months, from ULS and event viewer log entries.